# Is A In Column B Not Losing C

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In an excel spreadsheet I have 4 columns

```
A - A list of URLs
B - Date the URLs in A were created
C - Another List of URLs
D - The amount of traffic the URLs in column C got
```

I add some other columns but don't know what formulas to use:

```
E - Is the URL in A anywhere in column C
F - If the URL in column A is duplicated in C, how much traffic did it get
```

Hope this makes sense...and really hope you can help!

Thanks,

N

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
A - A list of URLs 
B - Date the URLs in A were created 
C - Another List of URLs 
D - The amount of traffic the URLs in column C got
```

You need

```
E - Is the URL in A anywhere in column C 
F - If the URL in column A is duplicated in C, how much traffic did it get
```

For E you have to [vlookup](https://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) with something like this in E1

```
=vlookup(C1,$A$1:$A$500,1,FAlSE) 
// Assuming your list is 500, if more change accordingly last value for A1
```

For F you can use something like this in F1, Vlookup returns "#N/A" if exact match is not found, so you can check for that in this column

```
   = If(E1="#N/A",0,D1)
```

Refer to Vlookup documentation on how to pass values to vlookup for looking up a value vertically in a column

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I have misunderstood this.

Column E)

In cell E2, you want to know if A2 appears in column C anywhere.
  For this you can use

> =Vlookup(A2,C:C,1,FALSE)

To eliminate all the #N/A's you can wrap it in an iferror.
  This will give you

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,FALSE),"")

Column F)

If you have found A2 value in column C you want to find how much traffic that URL had.
  A sumif will do the trick and will also be useful if A2 appears multiple times in column C

> =sumif(C:C,A2,D:D)

To avoid any errors wrap this in an "if" statement to only sum values that are not blank in column E

> =IF(E2<>"",SUMIF(C:C,A2,D:D),"")

NOTE* if you want to find if C2 appears anywhere in column A, you can use the process and swap the C and A values